# Linq to entities - filter on a child table via include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a one to many r/ship between two tables.  I am using Entity Frameworks 6.  Table 1 is called "Vote" and table 2 is "VoteInfo".  The Vote table has an attribute called "VoteYear" and the VoteInfo table has an attribute called "VoterId".  There could be many vote records in a given year but a voter can only vote once per a vote record.  My goal is to return a list of all votes
in a year that a voter has voted on.  I want to include the information from the VoteInfo table as part of this list.  This is how I want to return my result:

```html
<Vote>
<VoteDate>5/21/2015</VoteDate>
<VoteYear>2015</VoteYear>
<VoteInfo>
  <VoterId>1</VoterId>
  <VoteValue>Yes</VoteValue>
</VoteInfo>
</Vote>
<Vote>
<VoteDate>4/21/2015</VoteDate>
<VoteYear>2015</VoteYear>
<VoteInfo>
  <VoterId>1</VoterId>
  <VoteValue>Yes</VoteValue>
</VoteInfo>
</Vote>
<Vote>
<VoteDate>3/21/2015</VoteDate>
<VoteYear>2015</VoteYear>
<VoteInfo>
  <VoterId>1</VoterId>
  <VoteValue>No</VoteValue>
</VoteInfo>
</Vote>
```

I tried this but not working:

```
public IQueryable<Vote> GetVoterRecord(string Year, string VoterId)
{
   return _dbCtx.Vote.Include("VoteInfo")
  .Where(v => v.VoteYear == Year && v.VoteInfo.Any(i => i.VoterId == VoterId));
}
```

Comment: And what is "not working"? Isn't it being compiled? Does it return an undesired result (what exactly)?

Comment: @Hoborg It's not filtering by VoterID.  My resultset includes all voters.

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Look at the sample code in my answer. It is working as expected.

Comment: Includes can't be filtered. This is a known issue and there are many questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code satisfying OP's conditions is the following.

```
public class VotesContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VoteInfo> VoteInfos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vote {
        public int VoteId { get; set; }
        public string VoteYear { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VoteInfo> VoteInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class VoteInfo {
        public int VoteInfoId { get; set; }
        public string VoterId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then the code

```
            var v1 = db.Votes.Add(new Vote { VoteYear = "2001", });
            var v2 = db.Votes.Add(new Vote { VoteYear = "2001", });
            var v3 = db.Votes.Add(new Vote { VoteYear = "2002", });
            var v4 = db.Votes.Add(new Vote { VoteYear = "2003", });

            v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, new VoteInfo { VoterId = "3", }, }; 
            v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, new VoteInfo { VoterId = "4", }, }; 
            v3.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "2", }, }; 
            //v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "3", }, }; 
            //v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "4", }, };

            db.SaveChanges();

            // Each record corresponds to a vote in 2001 where voter #1 has voted.
            // VoteInfo for each voter in this vote is included.
            var votesIn2001With1 = db.Votes
                .Where(x1 => 
                    x1.VoteYear == "2001" &&
                    x1.VoteInfo.Any(x2 => x2.VoterId == "1"))
                .Select(x => new {
                    vote = x,
                    voteInfo = x.VoteInfo.ToList(),
                })
                .ToList();

            // Each record corresponds to a vote in 2001 where voter #1 has voted.
            // VoteInfo only for voter #1 is included.
            var votesOf1In2001 = db.Votes
                .Where(x1 => 
                    x1.VoteYear == "2001" &&
                    x1.VoteInfo.Any(x2 => x2.VoterId == "1"))
                .Select(x1 => new {
                    vote = x1,
                    voteInfo = x1.VoteInfo
                        .Where(x2 => x2.VoterId == "1")
                        .ToList(),
                })
                .ToList();
```

does exactly the necessary things.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create this. It is a little off from what I am trying to accomplish. Update your voteinfo seeding code as follows and run the query again. What I want to return is the 2 vote objects for 2001 along with their corresponding voteinfo object.  
`v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, };
 v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "2", }, };
 v3.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, };`

Comment: @degmo Well, I have updated my code according to your demand. Still I cannot see any obstacles here. The result variable `votesIn2001` will contain 2 records consisting of Vote objects and lists of VoteInfo objects. You may introduce new concrete type instead of anonymous type, sure.

Comment: my apologies, update as follows instead    `v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, };  v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, };
            v3.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "2", }, };`

Comment: Seed it as follows instead please    `v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, }; 
            v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "1", }, }; 
            v3.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "2", }, };
            v1.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "3", }, };
            v2.VoteInfo = new List<VoteInfo> { new VoteInfo { VoterId = "4", }, }; `

Comment: @degmo I have updated my answer, but replaced multiple `new List<VoteInfo>` calls with few ones because I suppose it is what you meant. Check that. Now the code includes two result variables for different purposes (see comments in code).